# While deploying function app in azure getting error

Tags: azure, function

Error : 
The function runtime is unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=3`enter code here`.0.2.0, Culture=neutral

Comment: Please provide more information about your azure function , code or other environment .

Answer (score 2):

Do you have extension bundle configuration in host.json like the one below

```
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
```

If yes, then changing the config to should resolve the issue. This would force the function to use a specific version of extension bundle that has service bus version 3.0.2 present.

```
"extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.0.0, 1.1.0)"
    }
```

> Note: If your function app is using C# pre-compiled functions then removing the bundles configuration is the right fix for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported in [Github](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3548),

Using `NuGet -package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus3` with NuGet -package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus works.

Feel free to remove package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus once "ServiceBus3" is installed.